# Lua functions accessing the table which contains them and garbage collection

Tags: lua, garbage-collection

Will garbage collection work properly if a function accesses the table which contains the function itself, i.e.

```lua
local lib = { }

function lib.a (x) <something> end

function lib.b (x,y)
  return x + lib.a(y)
end
```

Will `lib` and the functions inside it be garbage collected properly?

Of course I know about colon notation, but I want to be able to pass the functions as arguments to other functions.

I suppose one workaround would be to do this, but is it necessary/does what I want?

```lua
local weak_lib = setmetatable({},{__mode="v"}

function lib.b (x,y)
  return x + weak_lib.a(y)
end

for k,f in pairs(lib) do
  weak_lib[k] = f
end
```

Comment: What mean "garbage collected properly" and "improperly"?

Comment: Without memory leaks of course.

Comment: It's really hard to create a memory leak where there's garbage collection. The only way I can think of is to make a loop that continually adds lots of new stuff to a table without removing the old stuff from it. A weak table like you describe might solve that problem, but it's not clear from the question what stuff you want to keep, and what you want garbage collected.

Comment: I would agree with @luther that it is unclear from your question what exactly what you want to do--that is, how garbage collection factors into this as you do not show that step in your code. As Lua is a memory-safe language, it does not easily produce leaks. In your example, are you explicitly calling for garbage collection with `collectgarbage()`?

Comment: I'm coming from the Perl world where garbage collection is strictly by reference count so that cyclic structures *do* cause memory leaks unless you manually "weaken" the nested reference. I wasn't sure how it works with closures in Lua. I was afraid to cause a memory leak when the table is destroyed. Seems I'm fine though.